# Arithmetic Progression of 3 numbers which are neither multiples of 2 nor 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> $a, b, c$ are three numbers in AP which are neither multiples of 2 nor multiples of 3. Obtain an expression for the common difference of these three numbers.

This question came in a test today (it was an MCQ along the lines of *which one of these options is a possible value of common difference*, but I forgot the options).

I am clueless on how to formally solve this. To start off, $a,b,c$ belong to the set $S = \{x : x \not\equiv 0 \ \mathrm{mod\  2}, x \not\equiv 0 \ \mathrm{mod\ 3} \}$. I now have to find two numbers $a, c$ in $S$ such that $\frac{a+c}{2} = b \in S$. I could not proceed beyond this step. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.

Comment: You can easily show that the common difference must be a multiple of $6$.

Comment: @Peter how so? can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Begin with the eaiser part. What, if the common difference is odd and the first number is odd as well ?

Comment: @Peter nevermind, got it. Thanks! I'll write an answer up for this now.

Comment: As peter said : $(6k-1), (6k+5), (6k+11)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hints in the comments, here's an answer:

As said in the question above, $S = \{x : x \not\equiv 0 \ \mathrm{mod\  2}, x \not\equiv 0 \ \mathrm{mod\ 3} \}$.

Let $b \in S$, then $b \equiv u \ \mathrm{mod \ 2}$ and $b \equiv v  \ \mathrm{mod \ 3}, v, u \ne 0$. We have $b + 6k \equiv u \ \mathrm{mod \ 2}$ and  $b + 6k \equiv v \ \mathrm{mod \ 3}$. Similarily, $b - 6k \equiv u \ \mathrm{mod \ 2}$ and  $b - 6k \equiv v \ \mathrm{mod \ 3}$.

Thus, $b-6k,\ b,\ b+6k$ all belong to $S$ and are in AP, which means that the common difference must be of the form $\boxed{6k}$, or a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct and makes sense.

Comment: This isn't quite enough to prove it. You've shown that there _is_ a sequence with common difference $6k$, but this doesn't actually show that the common difference **must** be of that form. (To see this, imagine skipping any discussion of $b-6k$; the same argument would claim that any two numbers in $S$ must have common difference $6k$, which is false.)